# IE - When Uploaded New Image ,Old Image getting Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am  using `localStorage` to store image path. I have a Page where `New Image` is Uploaded by the User. I am resetting the `localStorage`, so that new image is applied, when post back is done.

In `Chrome, Firefox` it works well But in IE the same old image is seen.

As i clear the browser cache in `IE`, it shows me new image.

How to solve this in `IE` browser?

I am aware of the `querystring` trick appending to the image, but i cannot use it in my code, Is there any other way?

Comment: is another image url an option?

Comment: The url will be same in my case.!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a cache-breaker at the end of the image URL,

```
newImage.src = "http://localhost:8080/image.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
```

This will add the timestamp to the image.jpg request and this will make the browser look again for the image from your server instead of retrieving the one stored in the browser cache.

Or for a better way you can serve your image with `Cache-control: no-cache` HTTP headers.

```
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
```

By providing a date in the past, it won't be cached by the browser.

Comment: This saved my bacon today, Thanks. If there was away to tip you with Bitcoin I would.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<![endif]-->
```

Bear in mind that IE 10+ doesn't support conditional comments though.  If the newer versions are still having the same problem, dynamically changing the name of your image is the way to go.

Comment: I tried this `meta` tags, they are not working, Also removing `if` doesn't work either.

Comment: Then you either need to change the name of the image when it gets uploaded, or abandon IE users to the fate they so justly deserve ...